# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token;

Tags: java, json, spring, postgresql

please help me with this buck:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4010b719; line: 1, column: 31]
```

I send the following JSON Request:

```
{"title": "Test", "category": ["2","4","3",1], "description": "Test", "username": ""}
```

The error occurs on the "category" column.

I use a PostgreSQL DB
and I have the following model:

```
 @Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idea_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idea_seq", sequenceName = "idea_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "TITLE", length = 100)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
private String title;

@Column(name = "CATEGORY", length = 10)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
private String[] category;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 1000)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 1000)
private String description;

@Column(name = "USERNAME", length = 100)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
private String username;
```

I would be happy about any help. I am already having this bug for a few days.

Comment: Post the relevant code, and the complete excatption stack trace. Also, fix your JSON: `,1]` should be `,"1"]`.

Comment: When I google this error message three other threads on StackOverflow show up. Have you checked them if they fit for your problem?

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, I already posted the whole exception stacktrace. What is the relevant code for you?
@Lothar: Do you really think I would not check those first?

Comment: By default deserialization of array `ava.util.List` not array. So, you should change the field `category` as `private List<String> category;`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You category JSON contains a **number**:

"category": ["2","4","3",**1**]

This needs to be quoted.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Error still exists

Comment: @justus I find that hard to believe.  Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding?

Comment: If you are still having issues, try changing private String[] category; to private List<String> category;

Comment: Tried that. Still the same issue